# parsing dictionary to JSON

Tags: python, pandas, json

I used the following code to pass a json string as a parameter in requests.post method,

```
import json
data = {'Key': 'Value',"title": "hello world"}
# get string with all double quotes
json_string = json.dumps(data) 
json_string
```

output is

```
'{"Key": "Value", "title": "hello world"}'
```

How to remove the single quotes around the dictionary without using
print(json_string). So that I can pass this in requests.post like this

```
results=requests.post(url=url,data=json_string)
```

If I give the json_string without removing single quotes, it gives me internal server error.

Comment: json_string, **does not have single quotes**. They are **only printed** when one prints the string variable json_string. Maybe there is somethign else you do wrong. For example the post data json_string should be assigned to some variable in order to be valid post data. Then at other side the code reads the value of that variable and json-decodes that value to get the original dict back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass a string to requests.post's data argument, you pass a dictionary. So basically, instead of converting your dictionary to a string, you just do:

```
requests.post(url, data=data)
```

[EDIT]: From my experience, it is better to leave `requests` take care of everything, instead of using `requests.post(url, data=data)`, you can use `requests.post(url, json=data)`, which will format the header correctly.

See [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) for the doc.

Comment: what if the OP wants to pass json-encoded data to requests. So at the other side the OP wants to json-decode the post data instead of parsing url-encoded data? So far my feeling is the OP wants to json-encode the data, but it might be a fault of the OP

Comment: I doubt that this is the goal, but I might be wrong :)